# GlassFish on Windows vs RedHat

Tags: glassfish, operating-system

I have a basic three tier web application, and I want to use GlassFish.
Assuming same admin skills, any difference in having the host OS be Windows 2003 Server or RedhHat?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sooner or later you'll probably run in to problems when deploying on Win2K3 due to Windows file locking issues. But you'll learn to work around it - one way or another.

Also see [this](https://serverfault.com/questions/8764/glassfish-service-stop-when-the-console-is-logged-out) question:

All else equal, I would not select Windows as server OS for glassfish, but I would not strongly advice against Win2K3 either.

Answer (score 1):

I second fredarin. A dupe from an answer I posted on SO:

0  vote down

If you check the glassfish source, specifically ./appserv-commons/src/java/com/sun/enterprise/util/io/FileUtils.java, you'll see all of the contortions that Glassfish goes through in order to delete/rename files and directories on Windows.

This is a Windows problem, with its restrictions on deleting and renaming open files.

There are all sorts of tricks in there, including requesting a GC from the JVM multiple times in the hope of closing the file stream, "pseudo" renaming, sleep-try loops.

Some examples:

```
/**
 *Attempts to delete files that could not be deleted earlier and were not overwritten.
 *<p>
 *On Windows, the method requests garbage collection which may unlock locked
 *files. (The JarFile finalizer closes the file.)

/*
     *On Windows, as long as not all leftover files have been cleaned and we have not
     *run the max. number of retries, try again to trigger gc and delete
     *each remaining leftover file.
     */

/**
 * Windows has BIG issues renaming a directory that is open somnewhere -- e.g. if
 * a DOS box is opened anywhere in that directory.
 * This method will try to do a "virtual renaming" if there are problems
 * I.e. it attempts to do a simple rename, if that fails it will copy everything under
 * the original directory to the renamed directory.  Then it will delete everything
 * under the original directory that the OS will allow it to.
```

In practice this sometimes translates to borked deployments or redeployments on Windows, as some files cannot be deleted or moved and end up being left behind. Of all the Glassfish instances I run I've never had a problem on Solaris 10 and always have problems relating to this on Windows.

In short, any *NIX will be better for this reason alone, other platform admin considerations aside.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure there are any huge differences, assuming the same spec. I have heard some admins say that running Application Client Container (ACC) is faster on linux.